# Unable to assign 2 leading zeros in field creation

Tags: apex, soql, community, custom-field, create-records

Hi friends i stuck in a place i want to assign two zeros when ever any record is created.

My requirement is i have a number field.whenever i created any record i want to assign default with 2 zero's.So, in field creation time i assign two zeros.But it showing only one zero in the field.

Please don't say answers regarding with workflow & process builder because i have bunch of fields like that.And i don't need like

0.0.I need only in the format like "**00**".

Please provide me any restrictions are there.

Answer (score 4):

For Number fields the only formatting you can do is the amount of decimals and the decimal separator. Amount of decimals is configured in the field setup and decimal separator (and corresponding thousands separator) depends on the Locale set in your personal settings.

If you need a field to default to '00' you need to create a text field. You could then add a validation rule to check that only numbers are put into the field.